# "You always meet twice"-like badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers, badges

I was wondering if stackoverflow had a badge when the following interactions happen between two users:

1. user A answered a question from user B,
2. user B answered a question from user A.

And if such a badge existed are there statistics available for this (just curious about this metric). For example, how much time is separating event 1 from event 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there is no such badge, and indeed such a badge would add little value.

Furthermore it would encourage a type of behaviour that is discouraged: collusion amongst users.

In other words, it would be harmful to the working of the sites.

Comment: I don't really get your point. Isn't the very definition of badges to add no value? Questions, answers, comments, tags, search systems and even votes add value to the system, the whole "gamification" system is just for fun (or if you are pessimistic customer manipulation). What would be the point of "cheating" the badge system? And even if someone did cheat the badge system (which I guess is pretty easy). What would be the impact on the "working of the sites". Anyway, thanks for answering to give your opinion.

Comment: @cglacet Almost every badge encourages "good behavior", behavior that is beneficial to the health of the network. Other badges that didn't do that, such as the former badge Tumbleweed, have been removed.

Comment: @DonThousand I'm still not convinced inciting people to answer a particular user's questions would have a negative impact. And that would only occur if people were actually "hunting for badges" (which I doubt many people do, most people don't even bother register to SO). Or maybe you are referring to alternative accounts? Even in this case I don't really see the problem, it's like answering yourself (which is already possible). But I guess what's important here is that nobody seems to be interested by this. Maybe I'm just too curious about the odds of this happening.